# designing java classes to send the message to the queue through spring

Tags: spring, spring-jms, tibco

I am new to the world of spring jms , prior to this i have used the core java program without spring where we have manually create the connection factories but rite now i am learning spring jms   , rite now i have configured the xml but plesae advise how can i design corresponding java classes by which i can send the text message to the queue

```
    <bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://abcnet:707</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">abc</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">abc</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


 <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref local="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>test.data</value>
        </property>         
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value> 
        </property>
        <property name ="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property> 
    </bean>
```

folks as advise  i have designthe java class below but my question is that there should be another class which consists of main methid and which load my xml , i have design the below java class but still i know it is not correct if you do not mind pls can you please show how to design the java classes so that i can grasp and in which the depenmdencies are injected by my above xml pls..

```
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;




public class JmsQueueSender {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Queue queue;

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cf);
    }

    public void setQueue(Queue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void simpleSend() {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.queue, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("hello queue world");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-sending).

The simplest use of your `JmsTemplate` would be...

```
tibcoJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("foo");
```

...which will convert `foo` to a `TextMessage` and send it to your default destination (`test.data`).

The `JmsTemplate` has these high level methods as well as providing more advanced features if you need access to the session, or to post process the message after conversion.

Comment: i have edited the question i have design the basic java class but since i am beginner to the world of spring jms, request you to please help me as i am very eager to just drop am message over a tibco queue

Comment: See the [getting started guides](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) and in particular [the JMS one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/). It uses java configuration instead of XML, but you can use your XML file instead.